# Fazendo conexao a varios bancos com loop mysql

Tags: mysql, script, view

boa tarde

Minha duvida é relativo a conexão a varios bancos de dados no mysql para relatorio

gostaria do resultado anual do ano de 2016 em vendas, com isso quero tirar o resultado de cada mes, mas isso demandaria um select para cada mes e para cada banco..certo ?
por exemplo:
filial 01 mes janeiro vendeu um total 1000,00
filial 01 mes de fevereiro vendeu um total de 1000,00
ate chegar dezembro e depois fazer na filial 02 e filial 03
isso tudo mes a mes...

Existe como fazer um codigo reduzido ? quero fazer uma View para isso.. mas a logica do codigo pra mim não está muito clara.

Comment: Pelo que entendi as vendas ficam em uma unica tabela, não entendi bem a parte dos múltiplos dados, se puder ser mais claro.

Comment: são várias empresas, filiais, cada uma com seu banco, eu juntaria tudo em um banco só, mesmo que temporário